# dask / pandas, how to bypass boolean header error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, dask

Following a blog post/tutorial https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/08/14/out-of-core-dataframes-in-python/ I used the following code:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
columns = ["name", "amenity", "Longitude", "Latitude"]
data = dd.read_csv('POIWorld.csv', usecols=columns)
```

I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0f9a7022c6de> in <module>()
      1 from dask import dataframe as dd
      2 columns = ["name", "amenity", "Longitude", "Latitude"]
----> 3 data = dd.read_csv('POIWorld.csv', usecols=columns)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io.pyc in read_csv(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    182     kwargs = kwargs.copy()
    183 
--> 184     kwargs = fill_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs)
    185 
    186     # Handle glob strings

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io.pyc in fill_kwargs(fn, args, kwargs)
    147     kwargs = clean_kwargs(kwargs)
    148     try:
--> 149         head = pd.read_csv(fn, *args, **assoc(kwargs, 'nrows', sample_nrows))
    150     except StopIteration:
    151         head = pd.read_csv(fn, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    496                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    497 
--> 498         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    499 
    500     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    273 
    274     # Create the parser.
--> 275     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    276 
    277     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    584 
    585         # might mutate self.engine
--> 586         self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)
    587         if 'has_index_names' in kwds:
    588             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _clean_options(self, options, engine)
    681         keep_default_na = result.pop('keep_default_na')
    682 
--> 683         _validate_header_arg(options['header'])
    684 
    685         if index_col is True:

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.pyc in _validate_header_arg(header)
    214 def _validate_header_arg(header):
    215     if isinstance(header, bool):
--> 216         raise TypeError("Passing a bool to header is invalid. "
    217                         "Use header=None for no header or "
    218                         "header=int or list-like of ints to specify "

TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names
```

How can I bypass this TypeError, or input the csv in a correct format? A little more...

Using:

```
data = dd.read_csv("POIWorld.csv", usecols=columns, header=None)
data
```

Gives me (as expected):

```
dd.DataFrame<read-csv-POIWorld.csv-e5a4ce81b697e4068e03e56e51643bda, divisions=(None, None, None, ..., None, None)>
```

But then running:

```
with_name = data[data.name.notnull()]
with_amenity = data[data.amenity.notnull()]
```

Returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b460952b73e5> in <module>()
----> 1 with_name = data[data.name.notnull()]
      2 with_amenity = data[data.amenity.notnull()]

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.pyc in __getattr__(self, key)
   1196                 return self[key]
   1197             except KeyError as e:
-> 1198                 raise AttributeError(e)
   1199 
   1200     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: 'name'
```

So of course it isn't recognizing the "name" header if I use header=None. What should I do to get dask to recognize the headers?

Comment: It's possible that this was fixed in https://github.com/blaze/dask/pull/827 .  Can you try this again after updating from the development branch?

`pip install git+https://github.com/blaze/dask.git --upgrade`

Comment: yes @MRocklin I had just installed dask from pip and did an upgrade from there but this didn't come up, it needed the git option. if you write an answer I'll tag it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved in the development branch and will be fixed in version `0.7.6`.